# What's the reason of using Circular Buffer in iOS Audio Calling APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio, audiounit

My question is pretty much self explanatory. Sorry if it seems too dumb.

I am writing a iOS VoIP dialer and have checked some open-source code(iOS audio calling app). And almost all of those use Circular Buffer for storing recorded and received PCM audio data. SO i am wondering why we need to use a Circular Buffer in this case.  What's the exact reason for using such audio buffer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A circular buffer avoids overheads associated with allocating and releasing buffer space - this is particularly important in an application such as VoIP application where data will remain in the buffer for a very short time and there will be a lot of it.  Continually allocating and releasing storage can also lead to heap fragmentation which can also cause performance problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. There is another good reason for using Circular Buffer.

In iOS, if you use callbacks(Audio unit) for recording and playing audio(In-fact you need to use it if you want to create a real-time audio transferring app) then you will get a chunk of data for a specific amount of time(let's say 20 milliseconds) from the recorder callback. And in iOS, you will never get fixed length of data always(If you set the callback interval as 20ms then you will get 370 or 372 bytes of data. And you will never know when you will get 370 bytes or 372 bytes. Correct me if i am wrong). Then, to transfer the audio through UDP packets you need to use a codec for data encoding and decoding(G729 is generally used for VoIP apps). But g729 takes data by the multiplier of 8. Assume, you encode 368(8*46) bytes per 20ms. So what are you going to do with rest of the data ?  You need to store it **by sequence** for the next chunk to process.

SO that's the reason. There are some other details thing but i kapt it simple for your better understanding. Just comment below if you have any question.

Comment: How did you get 20 ms callback with AudioUnit? I'm curious on how you did it.

Answer (score 19):

Using a circular buffer lets you process the input and output data asynchronously from it's source. The audio render process takes place on a high priority thread.  It asks for audio samples from your app (playback), and offers audio (recording/processing) on a timer in the form of callbacks.

A typical scenario would be for the audio callback to fire every 0.023 seconds to ask for (and/or offer) 1024 samples of audio.  This thread is synchronized with system hardware so it is imperative that your callback returns before the 0.023 seconds is up. If you don't, the hardware won't wait for you, it will just skip that cycle and you will have an audible pop or silence, or miss audio you are trying to record.

A circular buffer's place is to pass data between threads.  In an audio application that would be moving the samples to and from the audio thread asynchronously.  One thread produces samples on to the "head" of the buffer, and the other thread consumes them from the "tail".

Here's an example, retrieving audio samples from the microphone and writing them to disk.  Your app has subscribed to a callback that fires every 0.023 seconds, offering 1024 samples to be recorded.  The naive approach would be to simply write the audio to disk from within that callback.

```
void myCallback(float *samples,int sampleCount, SampleSaver *saver){
    SampleSaverSaveSamples(saver,samples,sampleCount);
}
```

This will work!! Most of the time...

The problem is that there is no guarantee that writing to disk will finish before 0.023 seconds, so every now and then, your recording has a pop in it because SampleSaver just plain took too long and the hardware just skips the next callback.

The right way to do this is to use a circular buffer.  I personally use [TPCircularBuffer](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer) because it's awesome. The way it works (externally) is that you ask the buffer for a pointer to write data to (the head) on one thread, then on another thread you ask the buffer for a pointer to read from (the tail).  Here's how it would be done using TPCircularBuffer (skipping setup and using a simplified callback).

```
//this is on the high priority thread that can't wait for anything like a slow write to disk
void myCallback(float *samples,int sampleCount, TPCircularBuffer *buffer){
    int32_t availableBytes = 0;
    float *head = TPCircularBufferHead(buffer, &availableBytes);
    memcpy(head,samples,sampleCount * sizeof(float));//copies samples to head
    TPCircularBufferProduce(buffer,sampleCount * sizeof(float)); //moves buffer head "forward in the circle"

}
```

This operation is super quick and puts no extra pressure on that sensitive audio thread.  You then create your own timer a separate thread to write the samples to disk.

```
//this is on some background thread that can take it's sweet time
void myLeisurelySavingCallback(TPCircularBuffer *buffer, SampleSaver *saver){
    int32_t available;
    float *tail = TPCircularBufferTail(buffer, &available);
    int samplesInBuffer = available / sizeof(float); //mono 
    SampleSaverSaveSamples(saver, tail, samplesInBuffer);
    TPCircularBufferConsume(buffer, samplesInBuffer * sizeof(float)); // moves tail forward
}
```

And there you have it, not only do you avoid audio glitches, but if you initialize a big enough buffer, you can set your write to disk callback to only fire every second or two (after the circular buffer has built up a good bit of audio) which is much easier on your system than writing to disk every 0.023 seconds!

The main reason to use the buffer is so the samples can be handled asynchronously.  They are a great way to pass messages between threads without locks as well.  [Here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-02-03-ring-buffers-and-mirrored-memory-part-i.html) is a good article explaining a neat memory trick for the implementation of a circular buffer.

Comment: Very good explanation! I have an additional question: how should the callback being called which reads the tail of the buffer? My first approach was a while(true) loop which results, of course, in a very high CPU usage and a lot of "active waiting" for new buffers to come in.

Comment: I just use a plain NSTimer.  In this example I might set the timer to fire every 0.023 seconds (although I personally do it less often), then call the myLeisurelySavingCallback function in that callback. Notice how I calculate samplesInBuffer in the function? If it's empty it just waits until the next call, if it's got one or more buffers of samples stored in it it will process all of them.

Comment: Or put a sleep on the consumer's tread, like sleep(1000) every 1000 ms. And in stead of while(true) make it while(!stop). Which makes: while(!stop) { TPCircularBufferConsume(buffer, samplesInBuffer * sizeof(float)); sleep(1000);} Nice answer @dave234